# How to add vertical lines between headers columns in Tkinter Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am creating a Python Tkinter-based GUI. It has a Treeview widget, and **I need to add vertical lines between headers columns** (example from another, not Tkinter-based app is included below).

[image: Can I do something like this?]

I have been at [Tkinter Treeview heading styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708050/tkinter-treeview-heading-styling) This exact question was asked there, too (*in comments*), but nobody answered, even in two years. Is there a way to do something like this in Tkinter?

Here is what I've tried:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview, Style


root = Tk()
style = Style()
style.element_create("Custom.Treeheading.border", "from", "default")
style.layout("Custom.Treeview.Heading", [
    ("Custom.Treeheading.cell", {"sticky": "nswe"}),
    ("Custom.Treeheading.border", {"sticky":"nswe", "children": [
        ("Custom.Treeheading.padding", {"sticky":"nswe", "children": [
            ("Custom.Treeheading.image", {"side":"right", "sticky":""}),
            ("Custom.Treeheading.text", {"sticky":"we"})
        ]})
    ]}),
])
style.configure("Custom.Treeview.Heading",
    background="red", foreground="white", relief="flat")
style.map("Custom.Treeview.Heading",
    relief=[("active", "groove"),("pressed", "sunken")])

tree = Treeview(root, style="Custom.Treeview", show="headings", columns=("word", "meaning"))
tree.heading("word", text="Word")
tree.heading("meaning", text="Meaning")
tree.insert("", END, values=("Food", "what we eat"))
tree.insert("", END, values=("Drinks", "what we drink"))
...
tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"This exact question was asked there, too, but nobody answered"_ - when I visited that link, the question had an answer with 8 upvotes.

Comment: @BryanOakley I meant the question in comments: "Sorry to bother you, but would you happen to know much about changing Treeview.Row or .Cell or something to create grid lines even just in between rows. I could create a question with a bounty for you if you know how to do it". Nobody answered even in two years.

Comment: In future releases this will be included, starting from [tk 8.7](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/552.md)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
# ###############
# From: https://core.tcl.tk/tk/info/509cafafae
def fixed_map(option):
    # Fix for setting text colour for Tkinter 8.6.9
    #
    # Returns the style map for 'option' with any styles starting with
    # ('!disabled', '!selected', ...) filtered out.
    #
    # style.map() returns an empty list for missing options, so this
    # should be future-safe.
    return [elm for elm in style.map('Treeview', query_opt=option) if elm[:2] != ('!disabled', '!selected')]
# ############

# Create a Frame ( root = tkinter.Tk() )
dataTables_Frame = Frame(root, width=1400, height=1000, bg="light sea green")
dataTables_Frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan = 9, rowspan = 10, sticky="EN")
dataTables_Frame.grid_propagate(False)
# Get style
style = ttk.Style()
# Required to get heading colour to work
style.theme_use('clam')
# Required to get .tag_configure('colour', background='PaleGreen2') to work
style.map('Treeview', foreground=fixed_map('foreground'),  background=fixed_map('background'))
# Name Columns
cols = ['One','Two','Three','Four','Five']
dataTree = ttk.Treeview(columns=cols, show="headings") 
# Add Colour for headings
style.configure("Treeview.Heading", background='light yellow', font=fontButton)
# Add Colour to a Tag so alterative data rows are coloured
dataTree.tag_configure('colour', background='PaleGreen2')
# Add scroll bars
vsb_dataTree = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=dataTree.yview)
hsb_dataTree = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal", command=dataTree.xview)
dataTree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', in_=dataTables_Frame)
vsb_dataTree.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns', in_=dataTables_Frame)
hsb_dataTree.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew', in_=dataTables_Frame)
# Stop Resizw
dataTree.grid_propagate(False)

# ANSWER TO QUESTION
# Generate Table
for i in cols: # ['One','Two','Three','Four','Five']
    dataTree.heading(column=f'{i}',text=f'{i}',anchor='center')
    # if right justified text is required add - anchor=E or anchor=W for left justification
    # NOTE - How to 'right justify text' as been asked by others on 'stackoverflow'
    dataTree.column(column=f'{i}', width=150,minwidth=50,stretch=False, anchor=E)
# Add 'Separator line' to each column    
for i in range(0,len(cols)):
    # need - weight=1 for it to work
    dataTree.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
    # Note - sticky=W seems to align better than 'E'
    ttk.Separator(master=dataTree, orient=VERTICAL, style='black.TSeparator', takefocus= 0).grid(row=1, column=i, ipady=200, pady=1, sticky=W) 
# Add some Data colouring alterative rows
for i in range(0,20):
    if i % 2 == 0: # Even
        dataTree.insert("", "end", values=("24", "09", "2:00 AM"), tags=('colour'))
    else: # Odd
        dataTree.insert("", "end", values=("30 MM", "09", "13:00 AM"))
```