# How to make the cell lines visible in treeview tkinter

Tags: tkinter, treeview

Am working on creating a GUI which includes creating a table and I have done it using **treeview**.
Table is created successfully but cell lines are not visible for rows and columns.
Tried with grid option to create table but not sure how to move it to a specific position with the same.
PFA images for reference. First one [Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm6Hd.png) is the original which needs to be replicated and Second one [Created GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1re8e.png) is the gui which i have created.

Can anyone please help me for making the cell lines visible for rows and columns as it is in reference image.

Comment: Possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61282059/how-to-add-vertical-lines-between-headers-columns-in-tkinter-treeview