# Changing background color of ttk Treeview.Heading

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I'm going crazy trying to change the `background color` of the `ttk.Treeview.Heading`

I used:

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('Treeview.Heading', background='black', foreground='dark blue')
```

The foreground changes no problem, but the background won't change. I've searched around and found a few bugs with the background for the normal `Treeview rows`, but I'm not sure if this is related to that as well.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42738716/291641 for previous answer

Comment: Ahh that looks better. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `style_theme_use("clam")`

Here is the code

```py
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use("clam")
style.configure("Treeview.Heading", background="black", foreground="white")
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a start, but if I do that I'm going to be changing the theme for all of my widgets. Seems like an odd feature.

Comment: @RobertCriqui The explanation is that not all ttk themes allow you to change headings (and buttons) background color because those elements are made from pictures. So if you want to change these colors, you need to use one of themes that allows it, llke "clam", but not Windows or OSX default themes .