# Tkinter: TreeViw header background color change not working

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

In my following code, background color of header is not changing. Although changed font color and size is working properly.

'''

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Treeview demo')
root.geometry('620x200')

columns = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

style = ttk.Style()

style.configure("Treeview.Heading",font=('TkDefaultFont', 9,'bold'), background="grey",foreground="brown")

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings')

tree.heading('first_name', text='First Name')
tree.heading('last_name', text='Last Name')
tree.heading('email', text='Email')

contacts = []
for n in range(1, 100):
    contacts.append((f'first {n}', f'last {n}', f'email{n}@example.com'))

for contact in contacts:
    tree.insert('', tk.END, values=contact)

tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

root.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63239295/changing-background-color-of-ttk-treeview-heading>

Comment: Header color changes to Grey if I use "style.theme_use("clam")" But why I am unable to change background color  using "style.configure("Treeview.Heading",font=('TkDefaultFont', 9,'bold'), background="grey",foreground="brown")".

Comment: Not all themes give us freedom of choice, but you can get around this. There was a link in the comments on how to do it. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708050/tkinter-treeview-heading-styling/42738716#42738716>