# Active background color to treeview header

Tags: python, tkinter, header, treeview

How to set the active background color for the treeview heading. used the following code, background and foreground is working fine but active background is not working. please help me with this

```
ttk.Style().theme_use('default')
ttk.Style().configure("Treeview.Heading",font=("Calibri",12,'italic'),activebackground="#81C44C",background = "#0D94D2",foreground="White")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `style.map` to change the behavior:

```
pressed_color = 'black'
highlight_color='red'

ttk.Style().map("Treeview.Heading",
                background = [('pressed', '!focus', pressed_color),
                              ('active', highlight_color),
                              ('disabled', '#ffffff')])
```

As a [good source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42738716/13629335)