# Tkinter (TTK) - How can I put the treeview header always in focus?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

is there a way to put the treeview header always in a focus state? below is example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

parent=Tk()
parent.geometry("300x250")

tree = ttk.Treeview(parent)
tree.pack()

tree.heading("#0", text="Header", anchor="w")
tree.insert("", "0", "node1", text="Italy")
tree.insert("", "1", "node2", text="Germany")

parent.mainloop()
```

[image]

I want it just for a style reason, I like to see the header in focus. if I can't, is it possible change the header background color?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Active background color to treeview header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64954229/active-background-color-to-treeview-header)

Comment: @acw1668: no because the `background` option doesn't work with the "normal" ttk style. I don't want to use the default one, I mean using the instruction `ttk.Style().theme_use('default')`.

Comment: is it possible put the header always in focus?